# Find from a file list of and move in Unix

Tags: find, move

I have a list file with names of files, i want read one file name from the list at a time and  look for it under a directory structure with multiple sub folders and then once found move it into a diff folder.

Ex:

```
listfile.txt

Content of the file--
filename1.txt
filename2.txt

maindir
|--subdir1
|---subdir2/filename1.txt
|---subdir3/filename2.txt
```

read file names from listfile.txt one by one and move them to a diff folder say /destfolder.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
Kavin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a shell loop and calling `find` once for each filename:

```
mkdir -p archive_dir
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    find maindir -type f -name "$filename" -exec mv {} archive_dir ';'
done <listfile.txt
```

This would be slightly inefficient since it would continue looking for matching filenames even after finding the file (and if it found another one, it would *overwrite* the one already moved).

If using GNU `find`, you may add `-quit` to the very end of the `find` command to make the `find` process stop after the first file has been moved.

Showing it works:

```
$ cat listfile.txt
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
```

```
.
|-- listfile.txt
`-- maindir
    |-- subdir1
    |-- subdir2
    |   `-- filename1.txt
    `-- subdir3
        `-- filename2.txt

4 directories, 3 files
```

(running the above loop)

Then:

```
.
|-- archive_dir
|   |-- filename1.txt
|   `-- filename2.txt
|-- listfile.txt
`-- maindir
    |-- subdir1
    |-- subdir2
    `-- subdir3

5 directories, 3 files
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: to make sure it operates only once @Kusalananda, you can use the -quit predicate if available; alternatively tack onto the -exec something that kills the grep'd PID of find.

Comment: @webmarc Thanks. I'm on a non-GNU system, so looking up the GNU extensions doesn't come naturally. Added a note about it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the quick response. It works fine but only moves the first file from the list, doesn't move the seconds file, what could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy Does the second file actually exist with the exact filename listed in the input file?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes it definitely does. The file name is structured one below the other.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy Is your input file or your script, or both, written on a Windows machine?  That would mean that each line has a trailing carriage return. That does however not explain why the first file was moved.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy What do you mean by "The file name is structured one below the other"?

Comment: @Kusalananda am sorry, i had made a mistake, it works now :)

Comment: This also worked for me  `for file in `cat filelist.txt`; do find $source_path -name "$file" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} $archive_home ; done`

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy Yes, but you will notice that it fails as soon as any filename contains spaces or globbing patterns. Also, `cp` does not move the file, it copies it.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy It would likewise fail if the pathnames in `$source_path` and `$archive_home` contained spaces, as these are unquoted.

Comment: @Kusalananda agreed. But my source path and archive path is always constant. And even the file names are constant only thing that changes is the daily date. So, i think it should be safe :) Thanks again!